# Why there is no selectable Receive Handler while creating a Receive Location?

Tags: biztalk

As I'm learning to use BizTalk Server 2013, I'm following this sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334500%28v=bts.80%29.aspx

At step 4, it says how to create a `Receive Location`. While I'm creating one, the combo box for `Receive handler` is empty (which is said to select the `BizTalkServerApplication`).

**Question:** Why is that empty? Is that any configuration that I've missed?

FYI: I'm using BizTalk Server 2013 (Evaluation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, because there is no Receive Handler configured for the File Adapter.

Check the Platform Settings/Adapters/FILE.  You should see a Send and Receive entry.  If not, right-click/New and create the ones you need.

This can happen if the BizTalk Hosts are created outside the initial Configuration. It is also possible that you did not complete all the options in BizTalk Configuration.  You can check there also to make sure BizTalk Runtime is configured.

Comment: You're right. I forget to configure the BizTalk Runtime. It's working now.